# Querying WMI causes an BSOD (0x9c)

Tags: c++, com, service, wmi

I've written an Windows Server which uses the WMI feature of Windows to monitor system health. For that purpose, a WMI connection is opened, queried and closed every thirty seconds. That works quite well on Windows Server 2008 (R2).
On the other side, I have a couple of Servers running Windows Server 2003 x64, which run constantly into BSODs when using my Service (and only when using my Service). The Error code is commonly 0x9c, sometimes 0x19. Others told me that system memory may be corrupted, but it's very unlikely since all 2003-x64-based servers are experiencing that problems.
The Windows error log lists three error messages of type "WDMxWMI", without any further details, before the system reboots because of an bluescreen.

I don't know why this happens, and I neither know if, or how my program could be the reason for that, since I'm using the WMI exacly like the MSDN examples told me. Last but not least, it works absolutely fine on 2008-based servers.

I'll be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Is the windows Server 2008 machine also a 64x machine?

Answer (score 0):

A bugcheck of this nature seems to indicate a serious hardware problem.

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=329284

https://serverfault.com/questions/7060/troubleshooting-the-dreaded-0x9c-bsod